# Finding Characteristic Exponents for $x^2 (x-1)^2 y'' + 4 (x-1)y' - 4x^2 y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, characteristic-functions

I've found that the only *regular* singular point of this differential equation:

$$x^2 (x-1)^2 y'' + 4 (x-1)y' - 4x^2 y = 0$$

is $x = 1$.

How do I determine the characteristic exponents for it?